# How to perform text substitution within all files in a folder?

Tags: windows, perl, text, replace

I need to update a single parameter within a large set of .xml files. I read around and using a single line of perl at the windows command line I can get it to do substitutions a file at a time, but I am struggling to get perl to do all the files at once.

```
perl -pi.bak -e "s/(\d+\.\d+E-\d+)/2.2E-6/g;" test.xml
```

This works, however when I attempt to change it to something like

```
perl -pi.bak -e "s/(\d+\.\d+E-\d+)/2.2E-6/g;" *.xml
```

I get "Can't open *.xml: Invalid argument"

```
perl -pi.bak -e "s/(\d+\.\d+E-\d+)/2.2E-6/g;" .xml
```

Gives me "Can't open .xml: No such file or directory"

I tried to see if I could call it from within another perl script using system(), however that seems to take issue with the use of quotation marks, and may not the best way to do this.

Summary:

Problem - I have a large number of .xml files within which I want to change a single parameter. I have to be able to do this on a windows machine and ideally I would like to work towards a solution that would enable me to automate this in a script so I can loop through numerous parameter value substitutions (with a call to a separate program that takes the .xml files as an input in between substitutions).

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

> for /r %i in (*.xml) do perl -pi.bak -e "s/(\d+.\d+E-\d+)/2.2E-6/g;" %i

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked perfectly. Now to go read up on how it works.

Answer (score 3):

When I do some like this, I typically use the following pattern:

`ls *.xml | xargs perl -i.bak -p -e "s/<search>/<replace>/g"`

On Windows, you should be able to use the following pattern:

`for %f in (*.xml) do perl -i.bak -p -e "s/<search>/<replace>/g" "%f"`

See [Perl 5 by Example: Using the -n and -p Options](http://affy.blogspot.com/p5be/ch17.htm#Example:%20Using%20the%20-n%20and%20-p%20Options) for further details.

Comment: Note that the problem the OP is experiencing is specific to the *Windows* command line. Presumably, it would not happen in bash. The solution should be applicable to Windows as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `for` loop in a `.cmd` script. Something like:

```
for %%a in (*.xml) do (
  perl -i.bak ... %%a
)
```

Here's a handy `cmd.exe` [reference](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html).

Answer (score 1):

`use File::Find;`

UPDATE: you can use this one-liner:

`perl -we 'use File::Find; my $dir = shift; find (sub { $_=~ /\.xml$/i and system @ARGV, $_ }, $dir)' <dir> <other-one-liner>`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the Windows excuse for a shell does not do filename globbing (expanding *.xml into all files with a .xml extension).

Since the shell won't do it for you, you have to do it yourself.

This is easy to do in Perl, but it needs to be done before the "inner" code starts, so put it into a BEGIN block:

```
perl -pi.bak -e "BEGIN{@ARGV=glob shift} s/(\d+\.\d+E-\d+)/2.2E-6/g;" *.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

`find . -type f -name *.xml | xargs perl -pi.bak -e "s/(\d+\.\d+E-\d+)/2.2E-6/g;`"

this will pass all *files* under . (recursively) matching *.xml* to the perl command, one at a time.

Comment: And to allow for spaces (but not newlines) in filenames, use `xargs -d '\n'`

Comment: Of course you need a working Unix shell such as `bash` for this to work.